# Convert form data into PDF and store that PDF on Server

Tags: php, mysql

The consent form is a ***HTML*** modal (bootstrap) that has relevant fields and a signature field.

People can type in the ***signature***.

I would like to save all these consent forms, when people ***sign it***, in my server in pdf format.

Any idea on how to proceed.

I use ***PHP*** and ***MySQL***.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. The question is currently too broad and unspecific.

Comment: I did an answer for sign + TCPDF on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502688/tcpdf-and-base64-image/59502869#59502869)

Comment: Why bother storing the pdf?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) to make PDF using the content of consent form and the signature in input field